# Problemas con el formato de fechas

Tags: r, excel

Tengo un excel con columnas con formato fecha. Algunas fechas están como desplazadas a la izquierda. Si miro el tipo de formato es una fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo abro con R

```
 df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("prueba.xlsx", na.strings = "", detectDates = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para algunas de esas fechas "desplazadas" me las pone en un formato diferente al resto.
Además si hago `str(df)` me dice que es de tipo character.

Si abro el excel y pincho dos veces en las fechas desplazadas se mueven a la derecha y R me abre bien el fichero.

El fichero original tiene muchos registros, y no puedo ir mirando uno a uno para ir pinchándolos
y que se desplacen a la derecha.

He probado con algunos encoding pero nada.

Busco una forma para que R me coja bien todas las fechas.

Dejo un excel de [ejemplo](https://www.mediafire.com/file/b0vve6b8mbqru18/prueba.xlsx/file) con lo que me pasa.

Comment: Desconozco R, pero sé que en excel las fechas que tienen un formato diferente son las que se ven "desplazadas a la izquierda". Puedes probar seleccionando el encabezado de la columna y asignando formato fecha a toda la columna.

Comment: Gracias, pero el formato fecha a toda la columna no arregla el problema. Siguen hacia la izquierda y continua el fallo en R. Sirve pinchar en la celda en concreto y se van a la derecha, pero busco una alternativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las celdas que señalas están particularmente especificadas para que sean una cadena, lo puedes verificar en el Excel presionando <kbd>F2</kbd> en la celda y deberías verificar que el dato comienza en estos casos con una comilla simple, lo que le indica al Excel es que el valor de la celda es una cadena sin importar que el formato pueda interpretarse como fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución ideal es que edites estas celdas y elimines esta comilla, pero tal vez la solución más rápida sea importar y luego hacer dos conversiones a fecha:

```
df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("prueba.xlsx", na.strings = "", detectDates = TRUE)
df$F_NAC_OK <- as.Date(df$F_NAC, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$F_NAC_OK[is.na(df$F_NAC_OK)] <- as.Date(df$F_NAC[is.na(df$F_NAC_OK)],
                                           format = "%d/%m/%Y")

tail(df)

   ID      F_NAC   F_NAC_OK
93 93 1968-05-07 1968-05-07
94 94 1993-09-17 1993-09-17
95 95 10/03/1962 1962-03-10
96 96 1958-02-24 1958-02-24
97 97 1962-02-22 1962-02-22
98 98 08/03/1963 1963-03-08
```

Comment: No sé si es por la versión de excel, pero no veo la comilla delante de la fecha, tampoco dándole a F2, aunque el código va perfecto.